# I can't install Windows, because "The drive in which Windows is installed is locked"

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8, boot, installation, dvd

I am a total newbie to installing Windows.
My HP laptop running Windows 8 had some problem, so I decided to re-install Windows. During the installation I accidentally formatted the second drive mentioned as "Drive 0 Partition 2". I thought that it was the `C` drive, so I had to format it and re-install Windows to delete the viruses in it.

After formatting, I realised there was an error continuing the setup. It said

> Windows cannot be installed on drive 0 and 1

I could not install Windows on any of the given drives, so I tried searching online and later in the process of Windows repairing my computer. I got an error saying

> The drive in which Windows is installed is locked

I tried restarting my computer, but it didn't boot up. It said "your computer needs to be repaired" (I didn’t made it to Window's loading page). Now I cant do anything: I can't access my Windows or fix the

> Can't install in drive 0 and 1

error. Can anybody help me fix this?

Comment: Restart windows installation, delete all partitions then hit next to install W8.

Comment: Is there a way i can save my data on d drive .I have three main partitions C,D and E .I guess i have formatted C that is why it cant load windows

Comment: Easiest way is to remove the drive from the pc, use a hard drive to usb adapter kit and connect it to another PC and copy any data you want to the other PC. You need to explain exactly how you are reinstalling Windows, are you using a DVD or other method?

Comment: Dvd but i cant unplug it its my laptop

Comment: Most hard drive are removable in laptops?

Comment: Frankly, it might be better to hand it to the professionals, if you wish to see your files again. It would have been wise to take the backups beforehand.